# maven install with generate POM still produces a POM not found error

Tags: java, maven

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -DgeneratePom=true
```

The installation succeeds...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< XXXX:XXXX >----------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXX 18.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ XXXX ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\XXXX-svn\trunk\XXXX\ojdbc7.jar to C:\Users\QXV0615\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\QXV0615\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall491035374333687338.pom to C:\Users\QXV0615\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.096 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T07:30:13+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But then

mvn install

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< XXXX:XXXX >----------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXX 18.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.mq:jms:jar:7.0.1.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.993 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T07:30:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXX:XXXX:war:18.2.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2, com.ibm.mq:jms:jar:7.0.1.9: Failure to find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project depends on

```
com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2
```

and you are installing the JAR with `-DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7  -Dversion=12.1.0.2`, so it will be installed as

```
com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2
```

Note that the Maven coordinates do not match, either you install the JAR with the first Maven coordinates or you make your project depend on the second Maven coordinates.